# CrossMedia Plugin with Xamarin. Home Page shown after photo taken

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia

I'm using Plugin.CrossMedia in Xamarin Forms and have noticed that just after the photo is taken, the home page is briefly shown before control returns to the calling page. This is causing issues as the Home Page OnAppearing event is not triggered later.
I'm just wondering if anyone else has come across this and if they were able to resolve it.I have confirmed this on Crossmedia 2.6 and Forms 2.3.4 as well as Crossmedia 4.0 and Forms 3.1. and on multiple devices.

Thankyou for any pointers.

Comment: I am sorry, but without any code your guess is as good as ours. Please add some relevant code on how you take a picture and wherever you think the error might be triggered from.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis. I am using the standard code from a content page. The home page is displayed briefly, strangely more of an initial view rather than the current home page.  <code>    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                            {
                                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
                                SaveToAlbum = true,
                                CompressionQuality = 30
                            }); </code>